# how to use custom web part properties in CQWP

Tags: web-part, content-query-web-part, xslt

I have extended the CQWP and have several custom web part properties.  One is a text field named "Header" and I would like to use it for a header in my CQWP.  I know that I need to edit ItemStyle.xsl (I've done this fairly often) or add a new xsl file and reference that.  In the past I've referenced the web part title by using  and adding in  in the ContentQueryMain.xsl

My main question is how do I make that custom Header web part property available?  I've seen several posts about Parameter Bindings, but am unsure where/how to use this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update the CommonViewField of the web part to add the property.

I'd suggest reading the MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981241(v=office.12).aspx if you haven't already.